# Use Firebird Database to Lookup Data

Tags: database

I have installed my drupal in postgres. I've been using multiple databases in my customized module. Below is my settings.php:

```
$databases = array (
    'default' => 
        array (
            'default' => 
                array (
                    'database' => 'drupal-7.34',
                    'username' => 'drupal-7.34',
                    'password' => 'drupal-7.34',
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '',
                    'driver' => 'pgsql',
                    'prefix' => '',
                ),
            'import' =>
                array (
                    'database' => 'enrollment',
                    'username' => 'postgres',
                    'password' => '',
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '',
                    'driver' => 'pgsql',
                    'prefix' => '',
                ),
            'import_employee' =>
                array (
                    'database' => 'csudbnew',
                    'username' => 'sysdba',
                    'password' => 'masterkey',
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '',
                    'driver' => 'firebird',
                    'prefix' => '',
                ),
        ),
);
```

Below is my code in executing the query:

```
 $query = db_select('EMPLOYEES', 't1',array('target' => 'import_employee'));  
 $result = $query
     ->fields('t1', array('LASTNAME'))   
     ->condition('t1.EMPLOYEENUMBER','1016','=')    
     ->execute();
```

This is where I get the error.

[image]

I aready `enabled extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll` in my `php.ini`file. What should I do next? I can query in my postgres databases except in firebird. Do I have to do more configuration?

Ive been following this [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/362178). I downloaded the zip file in the site and unzip it in my `drupal\includes\database\firebird`.

Comment: What's the error you're seeing? Are using [`db_set_active()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7) prior to query execution so that query is targeting the Firebird DB?

Comment: @ShawnConn  --> I'm not using db_set_active(). I updated my post and provided an image of my error.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the following line:

```
$query = db_select('EMPLOYEES', 't1',array('target' => 'import_employee'));
```

It is selecting *import_employee* as target, and *default* as key, but in your settings.php file you have a *default* target with a *import_employee* key. Failing to find the definition for the target you select, Drupal fallbacks to using *default* as target and (without being instructed differently), to use *default* also as key.

You can do one of the following:

- Edit your settings.php file so that it contains information about the *import_employee* target and its *default* key. Keep in mind that the information about the database is given as `$database['<target>']['<key>']`, not `$database['<key>']['<target>']`.
- Change your code to always call `db_set_active()` before your query.

Answer (score 0):

The query object doesn't know about the `EMPLOYEES` table because it's currently switched to the your default Drupal database until you specify otherwise. Use [`db_set_active()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7) to change the active database:

```
db_set_active('import_employee');
//@TODO: Execute queries under the Firebird DB
db_set_active(); //Switch back to the default Drupal DB
```

Comment: That doesnt solve my problem. :(

Comment: You can try try the code snippet `drupal_set_message(db_query('select database()')->fetchField());` after `db_set_active('import_employee');` to see if the code reports back "csudbnew" as the active Database. If it's not setting the active database correctly, it might be an configuration issue with the Firebird PDO extension. If that's the case, I won't be much help there since I'm not familiar with that RDBMS.